# Time to file [file] for burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have a tag named [file](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file), 30 questions, 1 follower, no tag wiki. I think the tag should be burninated (i.e. deleted), since it serves no purpose. It is both broad and vague at the same time. Aren't all questions somehow about files?

You can not be an expert in "files". If you asked someone "What's your area of expertise in information security?" and they answered "files" you would be quite surprised. Perhaps therefore the tag is used quite randomly.

I think we would be better of using these more specific tags instead:

- [file-system](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-system) (110 questions)
- [file-encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-encryption) (246)
- [file-access](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-access) (79)
- [file-upload](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-upload) (135)

If it should not be burninated, it should at least get some usage guidlines that explains when it should be used and when not. But since I don't understand how this tag could be used in a meaningful way I can't write those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Agreed. I'll make some time later today to update some of them, and would ask others to also update over the next couple of days - not all at once or the front page will be full of these.

Comment: Great! I'll fix some as well (will be gone over the weekend, though, but after that). If you feel that you have other things to spend your moderator time on I (and others) can take care of it slowly. After all, there is no hurry.

Comment: I've burninated the remaining instances of the [file] tag so you can delete it now.